# Python regex recursion

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match brackets using regex in python:

```
(a (dcsd)) ()
```

I dont have internet on my desktop at the moment so I cant download new libraries. What is the best way of doing this when regex has no recursive features in python?

More clearly, and for a particular user who cannot read, I do not have internet on my main computer, just some mobile internet that I am using to post this question. I was hoping that someone could suggest a manual algorithm for finding the contents of matched brackets as the only answers I have found using the almighty google use separate libraries.

In that example I would need the result 'a' 'dcsd'

Comment: _i am sorry_,because there is no support of recursion in `re` library..you need `regex` library..BTW, how are you asking question without internet?

Comment: @rock321987: Good point!

Comment: If you just want to verify they are *balanced* - without a regular expression: ```s.count('(') == s.count(')')```

Comment: 1 - I have no internet on the desktop I need to the run program from. I of course have it on my phone. 2 - Google isnt helping because python does not seem to support recursive regex - hence I am asking for an alternative algorthim that does not involve downloading a new library - something I could not find elsewhere on here, obviously I googled it first

Comment: @user1212520 you can use stack..

Comment: Please explain what you mean by ```match```:  What would be the result of *operating* on your example?

Comment: @user1212520 i think you can also download the zip file of `regex` library on your mobile and transfer it to your desktop..it will be long process though

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to wait until my internet gets connected :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match brackets using regex, this sentiment is echoed by the comments you have received.

Regular expressions (regex) is a Chomsky Type 3 grammar, whereas finding matching tokens in a string requires a Chomsky Type 2 grammar (or above). Regular expressions have the same descriptive power as a finite automata.

To find matching tokens such as quote symbols, parentheses, braces etc. requires a computational model capable of describing grammars of Chomsky Type 2, namely a pushdown automaton. You might better recognize this as having a "stack".